# How to change Xlab,Ylab and values of XY-axis color and font size in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to change the color and font size of:

1. Xlab,
2. Ylab,
3. values of X and Y-axis
4. Panel border (color)

in R plot
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's code demonstrating some of the lower level plotting functions that provide the sort of fine-grained control that you're wanting. See the help pages of the several functions for even more options.

```
plot(rnorm(99), bty="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
box(col="dodgerblue")
axis(1, col="dodgerblue", col.ticks="green", col.axis="orange", cex.axis=2)
axis(2, col="dodgerblue", col.ticks="green", col.axis="orange", cex.axis=0.8)
mtext("Index", side=1, line=3, col="red", cex=2)
mtext("Value", side=2, line=3, col="purple", cex=0.8)
```

(The resulting plot is ugly enough that I'll let you run the code yourself, rather than reproduce it here!)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the ?par help page, as well as the relevant [Quick-R tutorials](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html) for an overview of the parameters you can change to embellish or annotate a base R plot.

Answer (score 2):

Using ggplot2 to create a plot with:

- panel-background
- axis-text
- axis-title
- and some way to add nice vertical lines to mark important days.

  ```
  your_data%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Transactions))+geom_line(colour='gold', size=1)+
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='#363636'), plot.background = element_rect(fill='#363636'), 
            axis.text = element_text(colour='white', size = 10), axis.title = element_text(colour='white', size=12), 
            plot.title = element_text(colour='white'))+
      geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date(c('2020-11-08', '2020-11-29')), col='red', size=1)+
      labs(title='Total Transactions')
  ```